# Sublime Text 3: confirm to delete file

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to confirm deleting a file from the tree (left hand side) or remove the option from the context menu?

It is too easy to miss i.e. `rename` and click `delete file` instead. Then the file is gone.

I googled and found it should be moved to the trash folder but either that doesn't apply to Win7 or to using network drives. As a result the files are actually deleted or moved somewhere I have failed to track them down so far.

Using Sublime Text (build 3083)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Important**: take a look at [iron77 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630637/3870761). It says that if you modify *Default.sublime-package* (options 1 and 3) this changes might be overriden if sublime text is updated.

### Option 1: modify side_bar.py file

**You can use [sublime API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) to show an ok/cancel dialog**. The code you are looking for is in a file called *side_bar.py*. This file is located inside the zip file *Default.sublime-package*. In windows this is usually located in *C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package* and can be explored using programs such as WinRar.

Inside that file locate `DeleteFileCommand` and add this 3 new lines, so it is changed from this:

```
class DeleteFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        # Import send2trash on demand, to avoid initialising ctypes for as long as possible
        import Default.send2trash as send2trash
```

To this

```
class DeleteFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        isSure = sublime.ok_cancel_dialog('Are you sure you want to delete the file?')
        if isSure != True:
            return
        # Import send2trash on demand, to avoid initialising ctypes for as long as possible
        import Default.send2trash as send2trash
```

We are showing a ok/cancel dialog and if the user doesn't press *Ok* then we return and the file isn't removed.

Notes:

- You will have to add the same code in class `DeleteFolderCommand` in order to confirm also when deleting folders.
- Is a good practice to backup your *Default.sublime-package* file first just in case something goes wrong. EDIT: use a different folder for the backup or the package could be loaded twice causing problems as the OP has said in his comment.
- As this is *python* code indentation is extremly important, don't
  replace any spaces for tabs nor add any extra space or it will not
  work (you can see it console).

Result:

[image: Sublime-confirm file deletion]

### Option 2: use an existing package

As [user leesei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665507/leesei) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30887741/3870761) you can use [SideBarEnhancements package](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) to achieve your goal. This package adds many other features to the file context menu as you can see in the following image, but it is a very good choice as you only need to install an exsiting package.

[image: SideBarEnhancements package]

### Option 3: remove option from context menu

Edit *Side Bar.sublime-menu* inside *Default.sublime-package* (see option 1) and remove this line (and if you want remove also the line reffering to deleting folders):

```
{ "caption": "Delete File", "command": "delete_file", "args": {"files": []} },
```

Comment: Very well done! Thanks. (For the backing up of `Default.sublime-package`: I named it `Default-Backup.sublime-package` inside the `Packages` and the package was loaded twice, messing up ST3's menu. Works well with `Default.sublime-package-BACKUP` though.)

Comment: @robbash You're welcome. Oh, I hadn't thought of that problem of the package backuped in the same folder being loaded twice, I've updated it in the answer.

Comment: Does anyone know where `Default.sublime-package` is nowadays with ST3? `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` has a `Default` **directory** (no file) and it is empty.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but think it's on `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/`. However [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630637/3870761) claims that this changes might be overriden if sublime text is updated

Answer (score 4):

While [sergioFC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870761/sergiofc)'s answers work great, I'm bit worried of modifying     `Default.sublime-package`, as it might someday get overwritten when Sublime is updated, so the fix would need to be manually re-applied after each such update. [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements), on the other hand, might have too many features for someone who only wants the confirmation when deleting a file.

Alternatively, you can add a simple confirmation dialog that should be more resistant to ST updates, by creating a file (plugin). On Linux it should be somewhere around `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/confirm_delete.py`, and if you're on Windows/Mac or this path does not work for you, you can simply choose from the top menu: `Tools` -> `Developer` -> `New Plugin` and later save as `confirm_delete.py` - thanks to [harrrrrrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3657140/harrrrrrry) for this suggestion. Code to put in:

```
from Default.side_bar import *

class DeleteFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        if len(files) == 1:
            message = "Delete File %s?" % files[0]
        else:
            message = "Delete %d Files?" % len(files)

        if sublime.ok_cancel_dialog(message, "Delete") != True:
            return

        # Import send2trash on demand, to avoid initialising ctypes for as long as possible
        import Default.send2trash as send2trash
        for f in files:
            v = self.window.find_open_file(f)
            if v != None and not v.close():
                return

            send2trash.send2trash(f)

    def is_visible(self, files):
        return len(files) > 0
```

This code is basically a copy of `DeleteFileCommand` function from `Default.sublime-package`'s `side_bar.py` combined with confirmation dialogs from `DeleteFolderCommand` from the same file, as Sublime has such dialog natively for **folder** removal.

Answer (score 3):

When I choose delete by right clicking on a file in the SideBar, I get a confirmation.
Maybe it's [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements). It is worth a try.

Comment: You're right, it is for sure caused by SideBarEnhancements package.

Comment: Thanks! I just find it's a bit too much and went with @sergioFC 's 1st solution.

Answer (score 2):

WTF a software that doesn't have a confirm dialog before delete. I can't believe this. Sad but true. Just stupid software!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to activate a confirmation. Usually the the deleted file is moved to the trash folder but as you mentioned this is only true for local files. Files on a shared network drive are still deleted immediately. This is a Windows 'feature' :(

> Locally the Recycle Bin is part of Windows Explorer -- and on the network you are NOT dealing with explorer on the server. Explorer locally isn't going to copy the file to the user's workstation just to put it into the recycle bin.

You CAN implement Microsofts [Shadow Copy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757854%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) however, then users can undelete and compare versions. This would be the only way so far for network drives until the sublime developer decides to make an optional confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

According to @iron77's answer, the path for plugin could not exist (in my case). An easier way is:

1) Click Sublime Text topbar menu `Tools` -> `Developer` -> `New Plugin`.

2) Paste the snippet

```
from Default.side_bar import *

class DeleteFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        if len(files) == 1:
            message = "Delete File %s?" % files[0]
        else:
            message = "Delete %d Files?" % len(files)

        if sublime.ok_cancel_dialog(message, "Delete") != True:
            return

        # Import send2trash on demand, to avoid initialising ctypes for as long as possible
        import Default.send2trash as send2trash
        for f in files:
            v = self.window.find_open_file(f)
            if v != None and not v.close():
                return

            send2trash.send2trash(f)

    def is_visible(self, files):
        return len(files) > 0
```

3) Save as `confirm_delete.py`.